# trying to filter a list with a specific type before adding to tablewidget. thought it would work like this any suggestions?

Tags: python, list, pyqt, qtablewidget

```
def show_types(self):
    for i in reversed(range(self.ui.tbl_collection.rowCount())):
        self.ui.tbl_collection.removeRow(i)

    Technology.load_from_file()
    choice = self.ui.cb_type_2.currentText()
    for t in Technology.TECHNOLOGY:
        t_f = filter(choice, t)
        row = 0
        self.ui.tbl_collection.insertRow(row)
        self.ui.tbl_collection.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(t_f.manufacture))
        self.ui.tbl_collection.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(t_f.model))
        self.ui.tbl_collection.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(t_f.type))
        self.ui.tbl_collection.setItem(row, 3, QTableWidgetItem(t_f.price))
        self.ui.tbl_collection.setItem(row, 4, QTableWidgetItem(t_f.dom.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
        self.ui.tbl_collection.setItem(row, 5, QTableWidgetItem(t_f.dal.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
        row += 1
```

i tried filtering the list with choice in combobox but program just ends with no errors

Comment: First of all, if you don't get any error in the IDE when the program crashes, then run it in a terminal or prompt. Then, what is `filter()`? If it's the standard python `filter` function, then it returns an iterable which obviously doesn't have attributes like `manufacture`, `model`, etc. If it's a custom function, then show us its code (and change its name). Finally: 1. the first for loop isn't necessary, just call `setRowCount(0)`; 2. you're setting `row` inside the loop, making `row += 1` is meaningless, move `row = 0` *before* the loop, or use `enumerate()`.

Comment: yes its python standard function.

Comment: @jakemcgahern What is `Technology` and what sort of data structure does `load_from_file` return? (NB: your usage of [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is totally wrong, since its arguments should be a *function* and an *iterable* - and it makes no sense to apply it to individual items).